# Why this code don't return the right video frame in cv2 (python)?

Tags: python, opencv

(Sorry for English Mistakes)
I'm writing a code that has this part:

```
def getVideoFrame(frame_number): 
    global path

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_number)
    success, frame = video.read()

    return frame
```

What's the problem with this (this part must return the frame passed by the param)?

I don't know much of python, but I think this is alright, I already debug so much my code, but I can't find the error and all my search around the code makes me think that the error is in this part, but I dont know where...

Comment: seeking (setting CAP_PROP_POS_*) is the problem. seeking is often complicated or expensive, or not precise. avoid it.

Comment: oh, I see! So if I need the exactly frame, I must loop around all the frames manually? Isn't that so expansive too, or there are no options?

Comment: depends on how far into the video you need to go and what each operation actually costs. -- if you _need_ seeking, you should use ffmpeg directly, e.g. with PyAV.

Comment: I believe I'll have to use ffmpeg, I need to check frames in different positions (it's not possible to predict which frame it will be, it can be one of the first or it can be one of the last)